# TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str

Tags: javascript, python, base64, angular6

I know this question has been asked much times, but please look once in my problem.

I am sending `base64` image data from angular to **python flask** but when I am processing that `base64` data on flask server(python3) then it is giving me the error

> TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str

My Javascript code is:

```
window['__CANVAS'].toDataURL("image/png");
```

Output of the above line is:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg....."
```

I am receiving same data on flask server as string.

Code on python server that is using above base 64 data is:

```
def convert_to_image(base64_code):
  image_64_decode = base64.decodebytes(base64_code)
  image_result = open('baseimage.jpg', 'wb')
  image_result.write(image_64_decode)
  img_rgb = cv2.imread('baseimage.jpg')
  return img_rgb
```

then it is giving the following error trace:

```
File "/home/shubham/py-projects/DX/Web/app/base64toimage.py", line 10, in convert_to_image    
  image_64_decode = base64.decodebytes(base64_code)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 552, in decodebytes    
  _input_type_check(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 521, in _input_type_check  
  raise TypeError(msg) from err 
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str
```

above python function working fine if I am converting the image using this function

```
import base64

with open("t.png", "rb") as imageFile:
  str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
  print str
```

please help me to solve this question? I am new to python.

Comment: ``b64encode`` returns ``bytes``, that's why ``decodebytes`` works, because it is expecting bytes, not a string (as the error message clearly states). See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html To solve your problem, convert ``base64_code`` to bytes or pass a byte-like-object to the function instead of a string. Side note:  you have successfully overriden the built-in ``str`` with ``str = base64.b64encode(...`` - don't do that!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`base64.decodebytes` only accepts byte arrays, use `base64.b64decode` instead it accepts Strings as well

Comment: by changing this I am getting new error `hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
`

Comment: This saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 1):

Encoded bytes will do.

```
bytes(base64_code, encoding='utf-8')
```