# Python - How to add line breaks to UTF-8 encoded text?

Tags: python, html, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I haven't included my code, as the issue only arises if I try to use a certain html file with it. The use of that file gives me the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2192' in position 21348:

This doesn't happen with the simple html files I created to test my program with. I can encode the problematic file in utf-8 and that allows me to use the html as a string in Python, but I'm having no luck getting line breaks back into the string.

After encoding of course, line breaks became a string of '\n' rather than a line break. Meaning my code block seen below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta
     name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
   />
```

becomes this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8" />\n    <meta\n      name="viewport"\n      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"\n    />\n
```

I would think there's a simple method to get the line breaks back, but I haven't found any examples. The replace() function hasn't helped me get anywhere, it gives me the error:

> TypeError: expected a bytes-like object, not 'str'

And to be perfectly honest, I don't actually know how to pass the function a 'bytes-like' object. Every bytes-like object I've tried has given me another error.

**So the main question is, how do I get the line breaks back into my UTF-8 string?**

But **bonus points** if someone can tell me why I'm getting the UnicodeEncodeError. The character in position 21348 is just an 'l' but it lies within this code block, if that helps at all. However character u/2192 is a → rightwards arrow. Thanks in advance.

```
<!--
    <div class="service-icon text-center">
      <img src="../assets/img/service/2.png" alt="" />
    </div>
 -->
```

**EDIT**

Relevant python code:

```
import data

enc_data = data.encode('utf-8')

#use of enc_data
for item in new_items:
    item.strip()
    pathlib.Path(file_dir, f"{item}.html").write_text(f"{enc_data}\n")
```

That's all I can see as being relevant to the Unicode error. I only use the enc_data variable once and that's here.

Comment: Have you defined encoding type? like" f = open('index.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(your html string)"?

Comment: @Epsi95 I'm using the text as a string, from another module. I imported that variable and then encoded it. Like for example: from pyindex import data | enc_data = data.encode('utf-8') | then later .write_text(f"{enc_data}\n"). That should do it shouldn't it?

Comment: Show us how you opened the file you are calling `.write()` on. Your error message talks about a charmap encoding, which is probably latin-1 or windows-1252 depending on your platform. If you write UTF-8 to a file that expecting latin-1 or windows-1252 you will get exactly that error.

Comment: don't use .write_text(f"{enc_data}\n"). when you are are encoding a string that means you are making bytes of that string with a given format. since you are using f string you shoud decode as .write_text(f"{enc_data.decode()}\n")

Comment: @Epsi95 I have tried that already but it brings me back to the UnicodeEncodeError unfortunately.

Comment: Can you define `new_items`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than encoding the data yourself, let pathlib do it:

```py
import data


#use of enc_data
for item in new_items:
    item.strip()
    pathlib.Path(file_dir, f"{item}.html").write_text(f"{data}\n", encoding='utf-8')
```

Otherwise pathlib will attempt to use your system's default encoding, which can't handle the right arrow character.

Generally, if you are mostly processing text, it's best to decode and encode at the edges of your application and work with `str` data (this is known as the "unicode sandwich" approach).

Comment: This works perfectly thanks, do you know of a way I could do the same thing for my replace line function text parameter? || replace_line(f'./realfolder/files/{item}.html', 9, f'    <title> {item} </title>' + '\n') || That seems to be my final hurdle. Would I need to implement an encoding parameter to my replace_line function?

Comment: Since your system's default encoding isn't UTF-8, you need to provide an encoding whenever you read from or write to a file.  So probably (especially if you are getting an exception that points to encoding as being a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to detect what you are doing. But `\n` represents line-breaks. How it is displayed depends how you interpret the string, e.g.

```
a = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta
     name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
   />
   
   \u2192'''


#on python console
a
#gives:
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n\n  <head>\n   <meta charset="utf-8" />\n   <meta\n     name="viewport"\n     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"\n   />→'


#and
print(a)
#gives:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta
     name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
   />
   
   →
```

Comment: I've added an example, I hope it makes enough sense. I'm kind of calling print to a separate file, but the Unicode error stops me from writing anything to that new file. If it's in utf-8 the entire string is written to the file. It's only the complete lack of line breaks that stop it from being usable.

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: expected a bytes-like object, not 'str'` means that you should to convert your variable to bytes-like. The best question is therefore:
**"How to convert a str variable to bytes-like?"**

You can convert a str variable to bytes-like with:

```py
your_string_variable.encode()
```

But you didn't provide any Python code so maybe what I said is not the solution. So check [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=replace+TypeError%3A+expected+a+bytes-like+object%2C+not+%27str%27+site%3Astackoverflow.com) for your error. For example, you can find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53340824/13123142).